# Unlock password dialog no longer granting access

Tags: 20.04, gnome, login, password

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 with Gnome on a Lenovo laptop.

About three months ago, my laptop started refusing my password when unlocking, both when the session timed out due to inactivity and when it was manually locked. No matter how carefully or how many times I enter my password in the dialog, it would tell me that it is incorrect.

The only way to get back into my session was to click the *change user* button (which exits the GUI and opens a full-screen text user/password prompt), then "change" to my same userid which is the only one on the laptop.

This is a bit of a hassle, but not excessively so. Heck, it's even maybe a little added security if you don't know to do it.

However, I'd like to fix it.  But I have no idea what program is being run to present the GUI dialog, and I don't know what it checks to validate the password that is entered.

Can someone more knowledgeable that me please point me in the right direction?